# Filter a data frame by row values but with tolerance

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(6.00001, 6.00000, 5.99999, 5, 2), y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

        x y
1 6.00001 1
2 6.00000 2
3 5.99999 3
4 5.00000 4
5 2.00000 5
```

I can use `df[df$x == 6,]` to quickly return the rows that has `x == 6`,

```
  x y
2 6 2
```

but what if I want to have a tolerance here? `all.equal` seems not applicable here:

```
df[all.equal(df$x, 6, 0.0001), ]
    x  y
NA NA NA
```

If I want to find the rows that `x` are very close to `6`, is there a short way to do it? Expected output:

```
        x y
1 6.00001 1
2 6.00000 2
3 5.99999 3
```

Comment: This is already said in the answers, but the base R answer would be : `df[with(df, abs(x - 6) < 0.0001), ]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `near()`, which is a wrapper for `abs(x - y) < tol`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(near(x, 6, tol = 1e-04))

        x y
1 6.00001 1
2 6.00000 2
3 5.99999 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr solution, but what if I want to test `>=` or `<=`? Is there also a helper function?

Answer (score 2):

Using *round*:

```
df[ round(df$x, 4) == 6, ]
#         x y
# 1 6.00001 1
# 2 6.00000 2
# 3 5.99999 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `df[all.equal(df$x, 6, 0.0001), ]` produces `NA` output is twofold.

Firstly, [`all.equal()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/all.equal) compares the entire object, rather than recycling the shorter vector and doing element-wise comparison.

Check out this example:

```r
all.equal(
    target = c(1, 1), 
    current = 1,
    tolerance = 1e-7
)
# [1] "Numeric: lengths (2, 1) differ"
```

Secondly, it is the output it produces. As you can see, the output is a character vector. You cannot subset a data frame with this.

The reason for this is in the docs, which say that the return value is:

> Either TRUE (NULL for attr.all.equal) or a vector of mode "character" describing the differences between target and current.

You can also see this in the `all.equal.numeric()` [source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/all.equal.R#L173). The logic is that it tries to build a message (`msg`) explaining the difference between `current` and `target`. If such a message exists it returns it, otherwise it returns `TRUE`:

```r
if(is.null(msg)) TRUE else msg
```

So if you want to use `all.equal()` (and I can see why you would) you could use `sapply()` to do element-wise comparison, test whether you get a logical value and subset on that basis:

```r
target  <- 6
tol  <- 1e-3
df[
    sapply(
        df$x, 
        \(current) is.logical(all.equal(target, current, tol))
        ),
]

#         x y
# 1 6.00001 1
# 2 6.00000 2
# 3 5.99999 3
```